# format array of object using reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, reduce

I have this:

```js
[
  [
    {
      users: {
        'ID': {
          stage: 21,
          city: 'london',
          data: 2345
        },
        'ID2': {
          stage: 21,
          city: 'london',
          data: 5325
        }
      }
    },
    {
      users: {
        'ID': {
          stage: 21,
          city: 'ny',
          data: 5761
        },
        'ID2': {
          stage: 21,
          city: 'ny',
          data: 5235
        }
      }
    },
    {
      users: {
        'ID': {
          stage: 21,
          city: 'stockholm',
          data: 7433
        },
        'ID2': {
          stage: 21,
          city: 'stockholm',
          data: 52365
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      users: {
        'ID': {
          stage: 22,
          city: 'london',
          data: 743
        },
        'ID2': {
          stage: 22,
          city: 'london',
          data: 5325
        },
      }
    },
    {
      users: {
        'ID': {
          stage: 22,
          city: 'ny',
          data: 152
        },
        'ID2': {
          stage: 22,
          city: 'ny',
          data: 61632
        },
      }
    },
    {
      users: {
        'ID': {
          stage: 13,
          city: 'stockholm',
          data: 2161
        },
        'ID2': {
          stage: 22,
          city: 'stockholm',
          data: 62176
        },
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

I want something like this:

```js
  [
    {
      id: 'ID',
      stages: {
        21: {
          cities: {
            london: {
              data: 2345
            },
            ny: {
              data: 5761
            },
            stockholm: {
              7433
            }
          }
        },
        22: {
          cities: {
            london: {
              data: 5325
            },
            ny: {
              data: 5235
            },
            stockholm: {
              52365
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      id: 'ID2',
      // same idea for this user
    }
  ]
```

`data` is just as example there more elements, not just one

I tried so far to use `reduce` `map` and/or `flat`

`array.flat().map(ar => Object.values(ar.players)).flat()`

but I'm not sure if it's a best idea to flatten it, and I don't know what to do after it, I tried to use reduce but none of my attempts was any were close to successes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested approach and build new objects for same groups.

```js
var data = [[{ users: { ID: { stage: 21, city: 'london', data: 2345 }, ID2: { stage: 21, city: 'london', data: 5325 } } }, { users: { ID: { stage: 21, city: 'ny', data: 5761 }, ID2: { stage: 21, city: 'ny', data: 5235 } } }, { users: { ID: { stage: 21, city: 'stockholm', data: 7433 }, ID2: { stage: 21, city: 'stockholm', data: 52365 } } }], [{ users: { ID: { stage: 22, city: 'london', data: 743 }, ID2: { stage: 22, city: 'london', data: 5325 } } }, { users: { ID: { stage: 22, city: 'ny', data: 152 }, ID2: { stage: 22, city: 'ny', data: 61632 } } }, { users: { ID: { stage: 13, city: 'stockholm', data: 2161 }, ID2: { stage: 22, city: 'stockholm', data: 62176 } } }]],
    result = Object.values(data
        .flat()
        .reduce((r, { users }) => {
            Object.entries(users).forEach(([id, { stage, city, data }]) => {
                r[id] = r[id] || { id, stages: {} };
                r[id].stages[stage] = r[id].stages[stage] || { cities: {} };
                r[id].stages[stage].cities[city] = { data };
            });
            return r;
        }, {})
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```